# Why org.jboss.util.naming.NonSerializableFactory has been removed from jboss 6.0?

Tags: java, serialization, jboss, jboss6.x

`org.jboss.naming.NonSerializableFactory` class in Jboss 6 extends  `org.jboss.util.naming.NonSerializableFactory` I have checked the source code of Jboss 6.0 but i didn't find org.jboss.util package there. I am surprised why this package is not there as `org.jboss.util.naming.NonSerializableFactory`is used by `org.jboss.naming.NonSerializableFactory`

If there is any alternative for this class in Jboss 6 please suggest.

Comment: Did you download the full JBOSS 6.0 Final source-code bundle?

Comment: yes i have downloaded full jboss 6.0 final source code from http://download.jboss.org/jbossas/6.1/jboss-as-distribution-6.1.0.Final-src.zip

Comment: Ermm ... that is for JBOSS 6.1 ... obviously.  If you need the JBOSS 6.0 source code you should find / use a different URL

Comment: I have jboss 6.0 source in my project. But yeah same issue is there for jboss 6.1 as well